# Custom query in getter to return specific value when missing part of composite key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model, composite-primary-key

I have a table (*Interaction_Data*) with a composite key consisting of 5 data fields. Four of these keys are provided as a foreign key by another class (*Interactions*). This gives me the problem of a missing key in my *Interaction_Data* table, so my desired data field always returns the first result since it is getting back multiple results.

In my *InteractionData* model, I am attempting to call a SQL query in my getter (See "*DataValueNetCost*" below). I want my getter to return a specific value based on input from another field in my table. Namely, I want to get:

> DATA_VALUE when DATA_DEF_ID = "NET_COST"

Interactions model:

```
[Table("INTERACTIONS")]
    public partial class Interaction {
        // NOTE: The primary key for the INTERACTIONS table is a composite key
        //       consisting of:
        //           - ACCOUNT_ID
        //           - CONTACT_DATE
        //           - CONTACT_SEQ
        //           - PAGE

        [Key]
        [Column("ACCOUNT_ID", Order = 0)]
        public int ACCOUNT_ID { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column("CONTACT_DATE", Order = 1)]
        public DateTime CONTACT_DATE { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column("CONTACT_SEQ", Order = 2)]
        public int CONTACT_SEQ { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column("PAGE", Order = 3)]
        public int PAGE { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ACCOUNT_ID,CONTACT_DATE,CONTACT_SEQ,PAGE")]
        public InteractionData InteractionData { get; set; }
    }
```

InteractionData model:

```
[Table("INTERACTION_DATA")]
    public partial class InteractionData {
        // NOTE: The primary key for the INTERACTION_DATA table is a composite key
        //       consisting of:
        //           - ACCOUNT_ID
        //           - CONTACT_DATE
        //           - CONTACT_SEQ
        //           - PAGE
        //           - DATA_DEF_ID

        [Key]
        [Column("ACCOUNT_ID", Order = 0)]
        public int ACCOUNT_ID { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column("CONTACT_DATE", Order = 1)]
        public DateTime CONTACT_DATE { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column("CONTACT_SEQ", Order = 2)]
        public int CONTACT_SEQ { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column("PAGE", Order = 3)]
        public int PAGE { get; set; }

        // IN THE DB TABLE THIS IS ALSO PART OF THE COMPOSITE KEY
        // BUT DATA_DEF_ID DOES NOT EXIST IN THE INTERACTIONS TABLE
        // SO I CAN'T NAME IT A PART OF THE COMPOSITE KEY
        [Column("DATA_DEF_ID")]
        [StringLength(60)]
        public string DATA_DEF_ID { get; set; }

        [Column("DATA_VALUE")]
        [StringLength(400)]
        public string DATA_VALUE { get; set; }

        //// Since we are using custom getters and setters we need a backing field
        private string _dataValueNetCost;

        [StringLength(400)]
        public string DataValueNetCost {
            get {
                // We need to get the specific DATA_VALUE when DATA_DEF_ID is "NET_COST"
                // This next section will call a SQL query to get this field and return it.
                SourceCodeContext db = new SourceCodeContext();

                IEnumerable<InteractionData> netCost = db.InteractionsData.SqlQuery(
                    "SELECT DATA_VALUE FROM PBDS.INTERACTION_DATA as id WHERE id.Account_Id = '@p0' AND id.CONTACT_DATE = '@p1' AND " +
                    "id.CONTACT_SEQ = '@p2' AND id.PAGE = '@p3' AND id.DATA_DEF_ID = '@p4'",
                    ACCOUNT_ID, CONTACT_DATE, CONTACT_SEQ, PAGE, "NET_COST"
                );

                string returnString = netCost.ToString();

                return returnString;
            }
            set {
                _dataValueNetCost = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Currently, the result of this is *DataValueNetCost* has the value of the first DATA_VALUE record returned from the query with only 4 of the 5 keys required for the composite key.

I am getting data based on an Odata call that sends the 4 primary keys to Interactions. I need to display *InteractionData.DataValueNetCost* on screen in my View.

How can I return DATA_VALUE when DATA_DEF_ID = "NET_COST" to a text field in my View?